# Scout Eclipse label positions

Tags: position, alignment, label, eclipse-scout

In Scout Eclipse with every field comes label for it. But my problem is that is a lot of free space there and because of that fields are smaller that they should be.

For example : 
[image]

I tried :

- To set label width in pixel: It works, but you should set and calculate it for every field and you can forget about translations, because text don't have same size in other languages.
- To set Label Horizontal Alignment to Right - text is positioned by fields but then free space is on the left side.

How to handle that?

P.S.
I don't need label without any free space, but with smaller one.

EDIT :

With spy tool it look like :

[image]

Comment: I do not understand how your grid is built. Can you add a second screenshot with the grid overlay? CTRL-SHIFT-F2 https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Spy#Layout_Debugger

Comment: Hy,.. How do I do it on a mac?

Comment: I found something but it doesn't look like demo.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send us the client code you are using? Is the screenshot a part of a TabBox? I guess the additional lines created by the layout debugger are created because of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

*I have no idea what your problem really is, here some generic advices I can give you (based on some guesses I have made. I will be happy to extend this answer, when I know more about your use case).*

### From-To fields:

When you have 2 fields for “From” and “To”, a good practice is to use a [sequence box](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/SequenceBox).

Here an example for a “from-to date” sequence box (taken in the [Widgets Demo Application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Demo#Widgets)):

```
@Order(50.0)
public class DateBox extends AbstractSequenceBox {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredLabel() {
    return TEXTS.get("DateColumn");
  }

  @Order(10.0)
  public class DateFrom extends AbstractDateField {

    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredLabel() {
      return TEXTS.get("from");
    }
  }

  @Order(20.0)
  public class DateTo extends AbstractDateField {

    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredLabel() {
      return TEXTS.get("to");
    }
  }
}
```

### Money field:

We have discussed how you can combine an amount and currency field in a sequence box in order to look like this.

[image: Sequence Box - Money Field]

See this solution: [Amount and currency field](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/812552/1424609/#msg_1424609).